# Extend string prototype : change the uppercase to lowercase and vice versa

Tags: javascript

```
 <script>

  String.prototype.swapCase = function() {
    for (var i = 0; i < this.length; i++) {
      if (this[i].toUpperCase() == this[i]) {
        this[i] = this[i].toLowerCase();
      } else if (this[i].toUpperCase() != this[i]) {
        this[i] = this[i].toUpperCase();
      } else {
        this[i] = this[i];
      }


    }
    return this
  };

  document.write("hello".swapCase());
</script>
```

And the output is still hello, no uppercase applied.

I am expecting sth like "Hello".swapCase() ➞ "hELLO"

Comment: strings are immutable.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Strings in javascript are immutable, so you can't actually change it's contents.

Better create new empty String and add value to it.

Something like this.

```js
   

String.prototype.swapCase = function () {
  var newString = '';
  for (var i = 0; i < this.length; i++) {
   var c = this[i];
    newString += c === c.toUpperCase() ? c.toLowerCase() : c.toUpperCase()
  }
  return newString;
};
console.log("Hello".swapCase());
```

Comment: A cool version without loops, conditionals or temporary variables: `this.replace(/([a-z]*)([A-Z]*)/g, function(_, lower, upper) { return lower.toUpperCase() + upper.toLowerCase() })`

Comment: Sorry, may i ask what's "?" and ":" doing here? I haven't learnt this method. What's it called?

Comment: ? is caller conditional/ternary operator . https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator